# Posting to WCF Service via HTTP

Tags: wcf, http, post

I'm having trouble posting data to a WCF Service via HTTP Post and send a redirect response back to the user.

My service looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IXXLeadServiceWCF
{
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "invoke")]
 [OperationContract]
 void CreateCallBack(Stream input);
}
```

With the operation contract accepting a web invokation as follows:

```
[OperationBehavior]
public void CreateCallBack(Stream input)
{
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input); 
 string s = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
 sr.Dispose(); 
 NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s); 
 string firstName = qs["firstName"];

WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Redirect;
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Location = "http://www.test.com";
}
```

And I'm posting to the service like this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://wcf.xxx.com/LeadService/LeadService.svc">
 <input name="firstName" id="firstName" class="txt_input" type="text" value="" />
</form>
```

I only get a blank page back from the post.  Are there restrictions on HTTP posting from another domain in WCF?

If somebody could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe your HTML form needs to be encoded multipart/form-data, yes? Also, your WebInvoke needs a method of POST, right? UriTemplate defines the URL that the method will respond to and the values it accepts as parameters.

EDIT: WebInvoke(Method="POST")

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wrapped my form in multipart/form-data but would you be able to advice of the correct annotation in order for the webinvokve method to accept a POST request? There are many conflicting pieces of advice on the net. Thanks